# Is it possible to select multiple files in the file upload window with extjs 5?

Tags: javascript, html, extjs

Is it possible to select multiple files in the file upload window using extjs 5?

Comment: I disagree with the vote to close.  The OP is not asking for advice as to which tool to use but rather how to configure a particular tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just adding attribute `multiple:''` like this:

```
var fileUploadButton = new Ext.create('Ext.form.field.File', {
        buttonOnly: true,
        hideLabel: true,
        buttonText: 'Upload Files...',
        fileInputAttributes: {
            accept: 'application/xml',
            multiple: ''
        });
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Still only single file selectable. (Downvote reason)

Comment: Try deleting cache of your browser, sometimes cache gets saved in the browser and changes are not applied until you delete it

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show names of the files you can make something like this:

```
Ext.define('Ext.form.field.MyFile', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.File',
    alias: 'widget.multiplefileuploadfield',

    multiple: true,

    afterRender: function(){
        var me = this;

        me.callParent(arguments);

        if(me.multiple){
            me.fileInputEl.set({
                multiple:'multiple',
                name: me.name ? me.name + '[]' : 'files[]'
            });
        }
    }
});

Ext.define('Ext.form.field.FileButtonOverride', {
    override: 'Ext.form.field.FileButton',

    fireChange: function(e){
        var inp = this.fileInputEl.dom;

        if(!inp.files || !window.FileReader || !inp.files.length){
            this.fireEvent('change', this, e, inp.value);
            return;
        }

        var arrValues = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < inp.files.length; ++i) {
            arrValues.push(inp.files.item(i).name);
        }

        this.fireEvent('change', this, e, arrValues.join(', '));
    }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

I did this:

```
        xtype: 'filefield',
        buttonOnly: true,
        listeners: {
            change: function (view, value, eOpts) {
                //  alert(value);
                var parent = this.up('form');
                parent.onFileChange(view, value, eOpts);
            },
            render: function () {
                this.fileInputEl.set({ multiple: true });
            }
```

Comment: Can you comment your solution?

Comment: acutally need to hack this file ext/src/form/field/FileButton.js with function fireChange to pass the files array to string join by ','